# iOS filtering for array with non-sequential dates

Tags: ios, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

I have a date to use as my start point which is not always todays date. And I have an array with event dates. Both dates are in seconds since time interval

Then i'm using `dateByAddingUnit` method to add/subtract either a day or week depending on filtering required

```
NSDate *filteredDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                value:1      //value + or -
                                               toDate:startDate //date
                                              options:0];
```

Then I get the date only value using `NSDateComponents` and convert that to it's time interval value and run my query on the array

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(time >= %d) AND (time <= %d)", time, filteredTime];
```

This all works great until I have an array with dates 12, 13, 14... 18.

How can I refactor this so once I get to 14th instead of looking for 15th it jumps to the next item if available in my array.

[Link to full method](https://gist.github.com/omerjanjua/979735c3effae1c0216bba848b142190)

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is a `double`, and you are cast them as `int` (which may lead to less information), so: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(time >= %f) AND (time <= %f)", interval, filteredInterval];`

Comment: Thanks will change that, but my ultimate issue is that once i've reached a date which is not followed by the exact next date in order. Filtering doesn't work. How can I encounter that problem so i'm not searching for next date but next item in the array using the given date

Comment: Could you show what's inside `flowEventArray`? An exemple of one item? Your ultimate issue is not clear.

Comment: `flowEventArray` contains an array of custom objects. One of the property of that object is `time` and `time` is stored as an integer. So the array can have dates `[@476996747, @477050304, @477160246, @477522364]` these translate to 12th Feb, 13th Feb, 14th Feb and 18th Feb. Problem is i'm using `dateByAddingUnit` if i'm on the 14th; this searches for 15th which doesn't exist in my array to predicate returns 0. So my logic needs to change instead of searching for 15th, search for next item in array not `date` which is 18th in this case.